# GITLAB CI Runner tags

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have 2 different stages, but i am using same runner tags for both the stages. so instead of writing tags in both stage can i write only one time somewhere and use that in both stage? This is not working.

```
before_script:
tags:
  - $RUNNER_LABEL

stages:
  - testE
  - testE2

test1:
  stage: testE
  when: manual
  script:
    - chmod +x gradlew
    - ./gradlew runE2Etests
 # tags:
 #   - $RUNNER_LABEL

test2:
  stage: testE2
  when: manual
  script:
    - chmod +x gradlew
    - ./gradlew runE2Etests
 # tags:
 #   - $RUNNER_LABEL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you'd like something like this (extending jobs)
You can override the "inherited" parts

```
stages:
 - testE
 - testE2

.base-job: &base-job
   tags:
     - $RUNNER_LABEL
   when: manual
   script:
    - chmod +x gradlew
    - ./gradlew runE2Etests

test1: 
  <<: *base-job
  stage: testE
test2: 
  <<: *base-job
  stage: testE2

#override example - The overridden definition is not concatenated to the base-job, it must be written anew
test3:
  <<: *base-job
  stage: testE2
  script:
    - chmod +x gradlew
    - ./gradlew runE2Etests
    - echo "DONE"
```